# Records disappear during Rails tests when calling PORO (transaction issue?)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, transactions, factory-bot, minitest

I have an existing application (Rails 6) with a set of tests (minitest). I've just converted my tests to use factory_bot instead of fixtures but I'm having a strange problem with records created and confirmed in the test and controller being unavailable in a PORO that does the actual work. This problem occurs inconsistently and never seems to happen when I run an individual test, only when tests are run in bulk (e.g. a whole file or directory). The more tests are run, the more likely the failure, it seems.

(NB I've never seen this code fail in actual use - it only happens during tests.)

### Summary

Previously, when using fixtures, every test ran successfully both individually and when run all together with `rails t`. Now, with factory_bot, a few of my tests often (but not always) fail, all related to the use of the same object that is defined as a PORO.

Drilling down, I have found that there's an issue with records sometimes mysteriously going missing or being unavailable within the PORO during the test, even though they're confirmed as present in the test and in the controller that calls the PORO!

### Details

In my application, I have a `RichText` object that receives some text and processes it, highlighting words in the text that match those stored in a `Dictionary` table. In my tests, I create several test `Dictionary` records, and expect the `RichText` object to perform appropriately when passed test data. And it does, when the individual test files are run (and always did when I used fixtures).

However, now, the records are created and available in the test and in the controller it calls, but then are not available within the `RichText` object created by the controller. With no `Dictionary` records available in the `RichText` object, the test naturally fails because no words are highlighted in the text. And, again, this only seems to happen when I run the tests as a group rather than running just a single test file (e.g. `rails t test/objects/rich_text.rb` passes, but `rails t test/objects` will fail within the same `rich_text.rb` test file).

It doesn't seem to matter whether I create the records with `factory_bot#create` or directly with `Dictionary#create`, which suggests it's nothing to do with factory_bot - but then why has this just started happening?

I do have parallelisation enabled in minitest but disabling it makes no difference - the tests still fail the same way.

### Code

Example test code that runs and passes, up to the last assertion here, which sometimes fails as described above:

```rb
test 'can create new content' do
  create(:dictionary, word_root: 'word_1')
  create(:dictionary, word_root: 'word_2')
  create(:dictionary, word_root: 'word_3')
  assert_equal 3, Dictionary.all.count
  ...
  # This next line is the one that calls the relevant controller code below
  post '/api/v0/content', headers: @auth_headers, params: @new_content_params
  ...
  # This assertion passes, as it did above, even though the error's already happened after the post above
  assert_equal 3, Dictionary.all.count
  # This assertion checks the response from the above post and fails under certain circumstances, as described above
  assert_equal @new_content_output, response.body
  ...
end
```

I've added checks to the controller as below and, again, everything's fine through this code, which is called by the `post` line in the test above (i.e. the database records are present and correct just before the `RichText` object is called):

```rb
def create
  ...
  byebug unless Dictionary.all.count == 3
  rich_text = RichText::Basic.new(@organisation, new_version[:content])
  ...
end
```

However, the `RichText` object's `initialize` method immediately fails the same check for these records - but only if the test is being run in bulk rather than individually:

```rb
class RichText::Basic
  def initialize(organisation, text)
    byebug unless Dictionary.all.count == 3
    ...
  end
end
```

Rails 6.1.4, ruby 2.7.1

Answer (score 0):

Having tried various things (like disabling transactions in the affected tests), I found that the root cause was a constant defined in the RichText class (a line I didn't include in the question!). It looks like there was a race condition or similar that meant that the RichText class sometimes ran before the database was populated, leaving it with an empty constant.

Replacing the constant with a direct database call resolved the problem. It does mean slightly more database calls but, on the flip side, does mean it's slightly easier to update the Dictionary table. (This happens rarely - on the order of once a month - which is why I'd put it into a constant.)

From:

```rb
class RichTest::Basic
  WORDS = Dictionary.standard

  def some_method
    WORDS.each do...
  end
end
```

to

```rb
class RichTest::Basic
  def some_method
    Dictionary.standard.each do...
  end
end
```